# (C# XAML) How to keep a rectangle within a field

Tags: c#, windows, border

I'm trying to create a field which contains a rectangle. While being draggable, the rectangle shall not pass the border of the field. Is there an element i can use as a border which has exactly that function?

Answer (score 0):

There is no element that will manage the bounds-checking for you, but the best option for the container element would be a `Canvas`.  This element uses absolute positioning (e.g. `Canvas.Left`, `Canvas.Top`) rather than relative positioning (using `Margin`, `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment`).  This make dragging and dropping (used to re-position the child elements) much more straightforward.

You would need to manually insure the `Rectangle` doesn't pass over the edge of the parent `Canvas`, but that is easy.  It would look something like:

```
private void DoMoveX(double left, double xOffset)
{
    if (left + xOffset < 0)
      Canvas.SetLeft(this, 0);
    else if (left + xOffset > ParentCanvas.ActualWidth - this.ActualWidth)
      Canvas.SetLeft(this, ParentCanvas.ActualWidth - this.ActualWidth);
    else
      Canvas.SetLeft(this, GetSnapValue(left + xOffset));
}
```

Where xOffset can be calculated from the `MouseEventArgs` of the `MouseMove` event and the original position of the `Rectangle`.  In the excerpt above, `this` is the child element (which has a reference to the ParentCanvas), however you could easily invert it so the `Canvas` or a `Window` or something is managing the movement.